# react native flatlist initialScrollIndex doesn't work

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

Flatlist doesn't scroll to the specified index when loaded

Checked and tried answers on Stackoverflow, but suggestions doesn't seem to work for me.
Please check out my code(simplified version).

```
  {!formState.values.loading && formState.values.projects.length != 0 && (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <FlatList
              data={formState.values.stages.slice(0).reverse()}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
              horizontal
              style={{ flexDirection: "row-reverse" }}
              ref={flat_list_ref}
              getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
                length: 300,
                offset: 300 * index,
                index,
              })}
              initialScrollIndex={3}
              renderItem={(stageData) => {
                return (
                  <View style={{ width: 300, marginLeft: 15 }}>
//Some other stuff
</View>
</View>)}
```